# Can I MySQL SELECT rows only where JOIN fails?

Tags: mysql, join

I'd like to perform a MySQL query such that:

`SELECT * FROM table_A JOIN table_B on table_A.id = table_B.foreign_key`

…but I'd like to return rows where there is **no match** in table_B for table_A. Is this possible? How can I accomplish it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You want to use a [`LEFT OUTER JOIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/join.html) and then a `WHERE` clause to only allow NULL on the joined table.

```
SELECT * FROM table_A 
LEFT OUTER JOIN table_B ON table_A.id = table_B.foreign_key
WHERE table_B.foreign_key IS NULL
```

Comment: Specifically, you should use an `OUTER JOIN`... `LEFT JOIN` simply implies the `OUTER`, but you could write this as a `RIGHT JOIN` as well.

Comment: Why check `table_B.ID` instead of `table_B.foreign_key`? (Presumably, it's possibly that table_B have no ID column.)

Comment: you are correct, I just quickly put it there as an example but corrected it as ID may in fact not be there. that said, you can check any column in `table_B` for null and it will work...

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_A
LEFT JOIN table_B on table_A.id = table_B.foreign_key
WHERE table_B.foreign_key IS NULL
```

Comment: That won't work because a JOIN will only return rows that exist in *both* tables.

Comment: Accepted because it had a working answer (not putting constraints on the columns of table_B) first.